# Вывод из списка в сообщении telegram

Tags: python, telebot

Цель состоит в том, чтобы выводить каждый элемент списка в новом сообщении с задержкой, а не в одном сообщении весь список. Подскажите, как можно реализовать, пожалуйста.

```
data = []
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data[0])
    sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data[1])
    sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data[2])
    sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data[3])
    sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, data[4])
```

Чтобы вывело сразу все значения в списке, которые на данный момент в нем есть, но в каждый элемент  списка в новом сообщении с учётом задержки. Как реализовать этот цикл правильно?

Comment: Прочитай в Telegram api про batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что полностью понял Ваш вопрос, но возможно данный код сможет Вам помочь:

```
data = ['Hello', 'World', '!']

for i in data: # Проходимся по элементам data циклом for 
    bot.send_message(i)
    sleep(1)
```

Однако учтите, что библиотека `PyTelegramBotApi` синхронна. Это означает, что пока бот будет выполнять даный код, он не сможет отвечать на запросы других клиентов. По этому, я рекомендую перейти на асинхронную библиотеку `aiogram` ([Документация](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/)).